# Render partial and passing a collection with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, haml

I am trying to render a partial using jQuery. The action flow is clicking a button, jquery does an AJAX call to my controller, and then on response, it renders the partial passing an array. No matter how much I try, I have been unable to achieve this. The html I set (which is ruby) is rendered as plain text and not ruby. And yes, I do have a _cart.html.haml file.

```
function updateCart( id ) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/items/add_item',
        data: {'id': id },
        method: 'POST'})
    .done ( function ( data ) {
        var cart = data;
        var cart_items = data["cart_items"];
        var cart_total = data["cart_total"];
        $('#cart-wrapper')
        .html("#{ escape_javascript(render(partial: 'items/cart', collection: " + cart_items + ", as: 'cart_items')) }");
    });
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

EDIT:
Added add_item method

```
def add_item
  cart = session[:cart] || Cart.new
  cart.add_item(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json do
      Create an array from the search results.
      results = {
        cart_items: cart.cart_items,
        cart_total: cart.total
      }
      render json: results
    end
  end
  session[:cart] = cart
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use dataType: script option as the following

```
function updateCart( id ) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/items/add_item',
        data: {'id': id },
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'script'})
    });
```

this send request to controller , from your controller do the following

```
 def add_item
   your logic goes here ....
   @cart_items = ...
   @cart_total = ...
   respond_to do |format|
     format.js {}
   end
 end
```

then create add_item.js.erb in corresponding view folder (I guess its in your items view folder) and then place the following code in that file

**item.js.erb**

```
$('#cart-wrapper').html("<%= j(render(:partial => 'cart', :locals => {:cart_items => @cart_items, :cart_total => @cart_total}))
```

and finally in your **_cart.html.erb** partial do the required each loop and your code like the following

```
<%- cart_items.each do |c| %>
  <%= c.name %>
<% end %>
Total : <%= cart_total %>
```

Comment: I have updated my post. I am not using a js.erb file and thus I can't do it the way you said. If I add dataType: 'script', it will never call the .done callback. I want to consume the data as a json file.

Comment: if you want to go with json data why you  need of rendering partial(cart), if at  all you want to go with json data you can do it with dataType as jsonp and rails4 offers to use json builder views or you can also use rabl for json views